# Show that $T(2^n) = \Theta(3^n)$

Tags: asymptotics, recurrence-relation

We have a function $T(n)$ defined by $T(1) =1$ and $T(n)=3T(\lfloor n/2\rfloor)+n$ for $n > 1$. We need to show that $T(2^n)=\Theta  (3^n)$.  How should I approach this question? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, try to solve the recurrence relation using the [master method](https://algorithmtutor.com/Analysis-of-Algorithm/Solving-Recurrence-Relations-Part-II/#The-Master-method).

Since $f(n) = O(n^{\log_2 3 - \epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon$, this is the first case of the master method. Therefore $$T(n) = \Theta(n^{\log_2 3})$$

If you replace $n$ by $2^n$, you will get your answer. i.e. 
$$T(2^n) = \Theta(2^{n\log_2 3}) = \Theta(3^n)$$

Comment: if T(n) = $\Theta(n^{\log_2 3})$, then $T(2^n)$ shouldn't be   \begin{equation}  $ \Theta(2^{n^{\log_2 3}}) \end{equation}

Comment: Use the power rule. http://www.math.com/school/subject2/lessons/S2U2L2DP.html